# How to add jasypt plugin to eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, encryption, eclipse-plugin, jasypt

So I am using 
Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplerrc3

and I am trying to add the jasypt - 1.9.0 plugin to eclipse

Since I am not experienced in this, I only tried one way which is

1- Download the zip file form the following url
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasypt/files/

2- Unzip the file into the eclipse subdirectory plugins

3- Restart eclipse

However it seems that there is something missing

Answer (score 1):

Go to your downloaded file and go to the lib folder. In there, you have a whole host of jar files. It is most likely the jasypt-1.9.0 jar you want.

In Eclipse: go to: *Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries*

Choose to add an External Jar and navigate to the location of the jasypt-1.9.0.jar

This will add the jar and its libraries to your project. Note: Look at the API for what you are using if this doesn't work - you may require a different jar to be imported instead/as well.

This is the standard way to add any third-party libraries to your project.